# Cannot assign to read only property 'current' in React useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref, recoiljs

i used react `useRef` in functional components to get link on html object and store it in Recoil atom. For example:

```
const Children = () => {
  const [refLink, setSrefLink] = useRecoilState(refLink)
  return <input ref={someRef}/>
}
const Parent = () => {
  const [refLink, setSrefLink] = useRecoilState(refLink)
  const someRef = useRef();
  setSomeRef(someRef)
  return <Children />;
}

export const refLink = atom({
    key: 'refLink',
    default: null ,
});
```

But when my Parent component ummounts I get error:

> react-dom.development.js:20997 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to
> read only property 'current' of object '#' in file
> reac-dom.development.js

[image]

I can't imagine what's the problem;

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: In your edited code, where does `someRef` come from in `Children`? (Also: ***Please*** try to avoid posting code that doesn't actually represent what you're actually using, then later changing it.)

Comment: Also: Storing a ref in state seems...wrong. Why do you think you want to do that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is any other way to tooltip for different elements? I want to just change links of anchor element to show tooltips in diferent components

Comment: That's a completely different question from the question you asked. I'd need much more context to answer it. I suggest posting it separately. But fundamentally: you just render different tootips based on data. No refs required.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, but tooltip position based on element postition. So i need to get current element position to bind it with tooltip

Comment: @dendroid - That's fine, you'd use a ref for that. But you wouldn't store it in state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that atoms are are frozen by default (see the [documentation](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/atom)) and a ref works by mutating the `current` property of an object.

You could prevent object freezing by passing `dangerouslyAllowMutability: true`.

```
export const refLinkState = atom({
    key: 'refLink',
    default: null ,
    dangerouslyAllowMutability: true,
});
```

Note that this will only update all subscribers if the ref itself is replaced by another ref. If a ref consumer changes the `current` property, subscribers will not re-render because the ref object is still the same object.

You could solve this by not using a ref, but by passing the ref value directly into your shared state.

```
// without dangerouslyAllowMutability
export const refLinkState = atom({
    key: 'refLink',
    default: null ,
});

const Children = () => {
  const [refLink, setRefLink] = useRecoilState(refLinkState);
  return <input ref={setRefLink} />;
};
```

In the above scenario we've completely eliminated refs and instead store the DOM element in the recoil state without the ref wrapper.

However like the [forward refs documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) mentions:

> React components hide their implementation details, including their rendered output. Other components using `FancyButton` **usually will not need to** [obtain a ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to the inner `button` DOM element. This is good because it prevents components from relying on each other’s DOM structure too much.

Without knowing much about the structure and what exactly you want to achieve, you could for example extract the relevant data in `Child` and store that in a shared state. But there is probably a better solution if we had more context.

Answer (score 41):

If you're getting this error in TypeScript, try listing `null` in the **type annotation**, which changes this from a `RefObject` to a `MutableRefObject`.

From

```
const myRef = useRef<MyType>(null)
```

To

```
const myRef = useRef<MyType | null>(null)
```

After doing so, reassigning `current` should not result in this error (e.g. `myRef.current = null`).

<sub>[Source](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-useref-react-hook-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-typescript-error)</sub>

Comment: It is indeed changing the type as you said @nelu. Do you know how TypeScript does it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just pass a `ref` as a prop.

Normally, a component hides its implementation so a parent component shouldn't be able to access a DOM element created by the child. But in the rare situation where you want to allow that on a component, you have to do so explicitly with `forwardRef`:

```
    const Children = React.forwardRef((props, someRef) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      return <input ref={someRef}/>
    });
// −−^
    const Parent = () => {
      const someRef = useRef();
      return <Children ref={someRef} />;
    };
```

More in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Comment: @3limin4t0r - I completely missed that name, thanks!!

Comment: @3limin4t0r i localize my problem, i stored ref in recoil atom, if simple pass to components it works fine

Comment: @3limin4t0r the reason is to fast access to ref link in different components. For example, i want to make tooltip, so i can change refs in store to show it.

Comment: (Why do you keep @ notifying someone else?) *"For example, i want to make tooltip, so i can change refs in store to show it."* That isn't how refs work. Refs are managed by React, not by you.